System.BadImageFormatException HResult=0x8007000B Message=Failed to load the file or assembly "
I have two dlls, a 64-bit dll and a 32-bit dll, I run the program under x64 and the 32-bit dll reports enter image description herean error, running the 64-bit dll under x86 reports an errorenter image description here
I tried to modify the target platform, but it still reports an error, I also modified the application pool in IIS to set enable 32-bit applications to trueenter image description here

You can not run both of them, you need to pick an arch (either 32 or 64 bit) and find the version of the other Dll that fits the arch.

What error is "enter image description here"?  O_o
